# Microsoft Ink InkAnalyzer "... is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)"

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.ink, ink-analyzer

i am getting a "... is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x800700C1)"

Exception with the following code, any suggestions how to fix it ?

```
InkAnalyzer analyzer = new InkAnalyzer(this.overlay.Ink, this);
analyzer.AddStrokes(this.overlay.Ink.Strokes);
// Exception
AnalysisStatus status = analyzer.Analyze();
```

Comment: You get the "is not a valid Win32 application" error when you execute the code you've shown?

Comment: yes, sounds strange but yes. Maybe there's a problem with an referencing
assembly like IACore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into exactly the same problem. Apparently the Ink Analysis API only work with x86 assemblies, and I'm running an x64 machine. I was targeting 'Any CPU', but had to target 'x86' to get it working.

More info [here](http://www.pringle.net.nz/blog/PermaLink,guid,ccbf8de7-b7df-4433-9ccb-378a9f28a0ea.aspx).